# How to create a CCSprite that is a Polygon shape

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cgrect, ccsprite

What I want is for the user to draw a polygon and for a sprite to be made in the shape of the polygon.  I already have all the programming done for the user to create the polygon, so I can read the vertices of any image drawn.  However, I seem to only be able to make sprites that are rectangular, using CGRectMake.  Is there a way to create a sprite image from a file that is polygonal in shape.  Like a CGPolyMake where I give it the vertices or something like that.

I don't know what shape the user will draw so I can't premake polygon sprites.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want to fill the polygon shape with a texture or do you just want to draw the polygon lines?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!  I'd like it filled with a texture.

Answer (score 3):

Cocos2D has no dedicated CCNode class for this purpose. You need to create a CCNode subclass and implement the draw-method yourself. That requires some knowledge about OpenGL ES.

You'll also have to triangulate the polygon so that you can fill it with a given texture.
You could use this C++ code for that: http://www.flipcode.com/archives/triangulate.cpp

This thread in the cocos2d forum is very helpful: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8142

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!  The thread helped me out a lot.  Apparently this is much more complicated than I thought, but I finally got it working now.